# application setup to avoid timeouts and deadlocks in SQL server DB table

Tags: sql-server-2008

My application accesses a local DB where it inserts records into a table (+- 30-40 million a day). I have processes that run and process data and do these inserts. Part of the process involves selecting an id from an IDs table which is unique and this is done using a simple

```
    Begin Transaction

    Select top 1 @id = siteid from siteids WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
    delete siteids where siteid = @id

  Commit Transaction
```

I then immediately delete that id with a separate statement from that very  table so that no other process grabs it. This is causing tremendous timeout issues and with only 4 processes accessing it, I am surprised though. I also get timeout issues when checking my main post table to see if a record was inserted using the above id. It runs fast but with all the deadlocks and timeouts I think this indicates poor design and is a recipe for disaster.

Any advice?

EDIT

this is the actual statement that someone else here helped with. I then removed the delete and included it in my code as a separately executed statement. Will the order by clause really help here?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1..` is pointless without an `ORDER BY` ..... also: do you have an index on `field` ?

Comment: I have created a unique index on that column yes and please see edit

Comment: The `ORDER BY` doesn't help - **it's required**. Which **TOP 1** row do you get - if you don't specify `ORDER BY`, then there is no order... you pick an undefined / indeterminate row. Is that OK in your scenario?

Comment: it makes sense; one question then: if its an undefined row...is that random which would mean less chance of deadlock right? thanks for your response

Comment: actually, testing it now and looks promising.

Comment: just got insufficient memory available in the buffer pool